# What is the source for the Arabic name of the penguin and when it is first used?

Tags: europe, animals, south-africa, arab

During Vasco da Gama's trip to the south of Africa, they discovered birds never seen by European eyes before which became named as penguins in most of the European languages. But in the Arabic language, the penguin called al-batriq. If you search for the source of this word, you will find that it is historically used for naming the Christian patriarch.

So my question is when and why this name was used for naming the penguin and had Arabs even seen penguins before the Europeans?

Comment: I do not know if it is just a coincidence, but *Albatross* sounds a lot like it and it is derived from `al-câdous or al-ġaţţās (a pelican; literally, "the diver")` (and penguins are indeed good divers). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatross#Etymology

Comment: As Arabic native speaker, I can say that al-ġaţţās is so far from al-batriq indeed al-ghattas is pure Arabic word unlike albatriq which looks like derived from some other language

Comment: Is it 'albatariq' as in your question, or albatriq as in your comment? If the later its source is probably the name of the Syrian Abu Yahya Ibn al-Batriq  who translated many Greek texts into Arabic.

Comment: This question might belong on the Linguistics.SE.

Comment: @user2448131 al-batriq is for single and albatariq for blural

Comment: I have edited the question and replaced albatariq with al-batriq

Comment: @user2448131 actually al-batriq as family name or father name was used but the meanig have no relation to the penguin as I found it is mean also in some books the general who has 10,000 solider under his control .

Comment: Many American bird names have family names included in their name, Lincoln's Sparrow for instance.I can't speak to naming practice of birds in Arabic, however.

Comment: It isn't uncommon for a new plant or animal to be given a common name based upon an assumed relationship to a superficially similar one that is known (e.g. "corn" in English). So the name could predate encounters with a true penguin.

Comment: The Arabs don't use the same words for the two concepts. The word used for a penguin is بطريق The word used for the Patriarch of the Coptic church is بطريارق I'm told also that the the Eastern Christian Patriarch takes the same name. My source is the Coptic Christian sitting next to me.

Comment: In current arabic the used word for the pattirach of the coptic is بطريركbut one of the old uses for the word بطريقwas for the pateroarch as per many arabic dictionaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name al-batriq was first used by bishara zalzal in the article named al-batriq. The article is  published in al-muktatef magazine on june 1878. In that article he talked about the penguin and he said "I used al-batriq as the Arabic name for this bird because in Latin it is named penguin which means the "chubby bird" and batriq means the same thing in Arabic"

[Link to the orginal article](http://archive.sakhrit.co/newPreview.aspx?PID=2294170&ISSUEID=9201&AID=184781)